# Remove element from ArrayField of PostgreSQL in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-1.8

I am using django 1.8a1 and have my model like this --

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    cart_details = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name.username
```

I have a row in my `postgres` db like this

```
select * from cart_cart;
 id |          cart_details           | user_id 
----+---------------------------------+---------
  1 | {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2} |       1
```

I would like to delete some items in cart details

I have written the following code

```
obj = cart.objects.filter(user=request.user, cart_details__contains=[product_id])
if obj.exists():
    obj[0].cart_details = obj[0].cart_details.remove(str(product_id))
    obj[0].save()
```

I also tried something like this, but this also didn't work

```
print obj[0].cart_details
[u'2', u'2', u'2', u'2', u'2', u'2', '2']
lis1=obj[0].cart_details
lis1.remove('2')
print lis1
[u'2', u'2', u'2', u'2', u'2', u'2',]
obj[0].cart_details = lis1
obj.save()
print obj[0].cart_details
[u'2', u'2', u'2', u'2', u'2', u'2', '2']
```

Don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help will be deeply appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh `obj[0]` from the database, as changes to database are not reflected to already loaded object instances automatically.

```
obj.save()
obj_refreshed = cart.objects.filter(user=request.user, cart_details__contains=[product_id]) 
print(obj_refreshed[0].card_details)
```

Also I kindly suggest you to follow [PEP-8 Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and uppercase your class names.

Comment: Not able to get the desired result. Even after the save, the changes are not reflected in the database.....

Comment: How do you check if the changes are in the database or not? Do you remember to commit your database transaction?

Comment: The problem is with the column cart_details... On any other column having type other than ArrayField I was able to update the value using the obj.save() method... There is no need to do a manual commit on db. I think their is some problem with columns of type ArrayField. Django orm is not been able to handle this kind of field (may be because django 1.8  is still under development phase)

Comment: Please reply:  How do you check if the changes are in the database or not? Post your code.

Comment: I just did a 'select * from <table-name>' to confirm if the row has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to update the cart_details column by slightly modifying the code (although I was not able to understand the reason)

```
product_id = str(request.data.get('product_id'))
obj = cart.objects.filter(user=request.user, cart_details__contains=[product_id])
if obj.exists():
    # This didnt work....
    #obj[0].cart_details.remove(product_id)
    #obj[0].save()
    #print obj[0].cart_details

    # This works....
    cart_object = obj[0]
    cart_object.cart_details.remove(product_id)
    cart_object.save()
    #print cart_object.cart_details
```

Comment: I think that what you're seeing is the lazy evaluation in the Django ORM.  Specifically, the query actually runs only when you say `obj[0]` and it fetches your row.  In the commented-out example, you fetch once and remove something from the array field.  THEN, you call `obj[0]` again, which runs another clean fetch from the db, and save that second, unaltered, fetched object.  So effectively, you do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing directly `card_details` raises `ValueError`, if element to be removed is not in that list,

but you can do this:

```
from django_postgres_extensions.models.functions import ArrayRemove
cart.objects.filter(
   cart_details__contains=[element]
).update(
   cart_details=ArrayRemove('cart_details', element)
)
```